# System.LimitException: Apex heap size too large Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex

Map sObjectsToClone = Map of child object along with there relationship name.

I have to clone given children records to each opportunity in a Batch.

```
void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Opportunity> batch) {
    List<Opportunity> OpportunityList = new  List<Opportunity>();
    for(Opportunity opp : batch) {
        OpportunityList.add(opp);
    }
    insert OpportunityList;

List<sObject> childObjectStore = new List<sObject>();
for(sObject sob : sObjectsToClone.keySet()) {
    //List<sObject> childObjectStore = new List<sObject>();
    for(Opportunity sOppy : OpportunityList) {
          sObject clone = sob.clone(false, true);
          clone.put(sObjectsToClone.get(sob), sOppy.Id);
          system.debug('Clone :: '+clone);
          childObjectStore.add(clone);
     }
    //insert childObjectStore;
  }
insert childObjectStore;
}
```

This code is work fine if OpportunityList size is small(say 10) but if OpportunityList size is more(say more than 100) it will throw `System.LimitException: Apex heap size too large:` exception.

Please suggest any solution.

Comment: I assume you have some more logic before this piece of code which consume a lot of heap.

Comment: You are right Chiz, Please have a look for edited post

Comment: In this case I assume that query which you use to retrieve Opportunities contains a lot of fields instead of just Id (which you use in your logic). Try to reduce number of fields in your query.

Comment: You are having three lists of Opportunities. First is batch, then OpportunityList with the same size and ... Oh, you have a map of Opportunities. I believe it's stateful. I think you should use stable scope (in terms of number of elements processed at one time in a batch).

Comment: Thanks Chiz for your quick reply, I posted same question on stackexchange as guest so I am unable to add comments there :( - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28907/system-limitexception-apex-heap-size-too-large-salesforce#  here you said, it will work for small batch size, but if i set batch size as 100, and execute the code, it will again throws the same exception.

Comment: Try 50. You need to find that number which won't fire exception.

Answer (score 0):

- First of all the below code is doing nothing but increase the heap size.

  List OpportunityList = new  List();

  for(Opportunity opp : batch) {
  OpportunityList.add(opp);
  }

  insert OpportunityList;
- you have created new list 'OpportunityList' which is an exact copy of list 'batch'. So the list 'OpportunityList' has occupied the heap size equal to 'batch' list heap size which is completely a waste of available heap size.
- don't create 'OpportunityList' list and simply use the list 'batch'.
- this is batch class so the available heap size is 12MB, So try to fetch records with only the required fields using SOQL leading to less heap size usage.
- another thing you can do is reduce the Batch Scope Size according to your need, so each batch will process less records and heap size will not exceed.